# Contour Polygons Missing coastline using QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, symbology, contour

I have a base DEM for which I'm creating some contour polygons. Once I've run the tool, I get the polygons without the landmass' coastline, which I'd like to have, obviously.

My workflow (see screen capture below):

**01 -** The DEM (blurred to get smooth curves), showing the coastline.

**02 -** The "Contour Polygon" tool settings, applied to the DEM.

**03 -** The result, with my hypsometric tint of choice. All is well, except that the coastline has disappeared under the waves.

How do I get the coastline back?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is the DEM value of the ocean? 0, nodata, ?

Comment: Do you have any heights below 0,if not then there is no way to get a 0 contour

Comment: No heights below zero, no. So, that's why I can't have a coastline when running the tool at 100m? I do get the coastline, with some natural-looking variations here and there, when I run the tool at 10m, which is way too small. Anyway, this is all very interesting as I didn't consider this issue when I set out to create this fantasy DEM. I'm going to see what happens if I create a double of the coastline, and extend it further out than the actual one, although at a "minus height" (I'll call it the first bathymetry depth).